# Can a list of internal links be partly hidden in a scrolling container and repetitive anchor text removed without hurting SEO?

Tags: seo, links, hyperlink, accessibility, anchor-text

We are re-designing our home page and for some aesthetic reason deciding to make access to rest of our internal links (inside cards categories) by scrolling the cards and normally a portion of these hyperlinks hide in scrolling container.

Are these links are SEO friendly and also transfer right authority vs other hyperlinks to their target internal pages?
For better accessibility and also keeping close our service pages to home page because of better authority, we want to design several lists include hyperlinks of our target pages combine of Service + Geo location.
something like below:

> **Quickly find Doctors by region and procedures:**
>
> **Nose job**
>
> Nose job in Turkey
>
> Nose job in Germany
>
> Nose job in south Korea
>
> **Face lift**
>
> Face lift in Turkey
>
> Face lift  in Germany
>
> Face lift in south Korea

The problem is, the service name repeated several times in all rows, 
it is better to omit service name like below:

> **Face lift**
>
> Turkey
>
> Germany
>
> south Korea

Anchor text for internal linking is very important for crawlers, and the focus keyword of these internal pages are Service name + location ( Face lift in Turkey )
Is that okay to summarize these anchor text like above (Turkey)?

Answer (score 1):

It is better not to repeat the service name for each link.  There are several reasons for this:

- It is bad usability to repeat the service name on each link.   Users will find it awkward to have to read so much repeated text.  Users can scan a list of countries much more easily knowing that they all have the context of the heading.
- Internal link anchor text does not effect SEO much.  Google weight external link anchor text keywords pretty heavily, but Google doesn't seem to apply too much weight anchor text of links used internally within your site.   I've experimented with this and found no SEO bump from adding keywords to internal anchor text.
- Repeating a keyword in each link can actually hurt SEO.  Google views excessive keyword repetition as "keyword stuffing."  Google will actually make rankings worse when keywords are used too much, such as in every link in a list.   Seeing a ranking drop from using keywords too much is sometimes called an "over-optimization penalty."

Answer (score 0):

If you hide with CSS, **and** that kind of structure is exactly what your users need, then it should be okay (if not using hundreds of extra links).

As long as you keep your "signal" links (those with long tail keywords), everything will be fine.

Just keep in mind, using too much links and too much pages will result in less "SEO power" for each individual page.